# Laravel mix transpile dependency

Tags: laravel, typescript, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to use the [vuex-module-decorators](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators) library in a laravel mix project (using typescript). But I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor VuexModule cannot be invoked without 'new'`. This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/issues/11) and can be resolved by adding `transpileDependencies: ['vuex-module-decorators']` to my `vue.config.js` file which will tell babel to transpile the package.

Since I'm using laravel mix, adding a `vue.config.js` file doesn't do anything. And I can't figure out how to tell laravel mix to transpile the `vuex-module-decorators` dependency.

I tried adding `{ test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['babel-loader'] },` to the webpack config in `webpack.mix.js` (also with explicitly including the dependency) but it doesn't work.

So how can I tell laravel mix to transpile the vuex-module-decorators dependency (to es5)?

If it helps, here's my `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix
  .ts('resources/ts/app.ts', 'public/js')
  .stylus('resources/stylus/app.styl', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to point `babel-loader` at all `.js` files and that worked:

```
// In webpack.mix.js
mix.webpackConfig({
   module: {
     rules: [{
       test: /\.js?$/,
       use: [{
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         options: mix.config.babel()
       }]
     }]
   }
 });
```

However your compile times will be reduced if use a more specific `test` to target only the modules you need to transpile:

```
    test: /node_modules\/(vuex-module-decorators|vuex-persist)\/.+\.js$/,
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. However, if anybody from the team uses Windows, test pattern must match / and also \. So your test should be https://pastebin.com/apAUmpj3 ( sorry for the link, but I cannot paste it here without formatting would change it)

Answer (score 0):

I published a Laravel Mix extension that handles transpilation of `node_modules` dependencies: [Laravel Mix Transpile Node Modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix-transpile-node-modules).

```js
// Transpile all node_modules dependencies
mix.transpileNodeModules()

// Transpile selected dependencies
mix.transpileNodeModules(['swiper', 'dom7'])
```