# Babel not transpiling node_modules using Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, babeljs, laravel-mix

I am trying to enable support for IE 11 in my application. However, some of my dependencies haven't transpiled the code to es5. Therefor, I tried added one of them to my rules, but it still doesn't transpile that dependency.

This is how I am including my dependency, this time being [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps). However the produced code still contains `Object.entries` after running `npm run dev`.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /node_modules\/(vue2-google-maps)\/.+\.js$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: mix.config.babel()
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract()
    .babel(['public/js/manifest.js'], 'public/js/manifest.es5.js')
    .babel(['public/js/vendor.js'], 'public/js/vendor.es5.js')
    .babel(['public/js/app.js'], 'public/js/app.es5.js')
```

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344641/laravel-mix-transpile-dependency), but the answer didn't help me yet. [Here is another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098621/laravel-mix-not-transpiling-vendor-js-to-es5), but there is no answer in that one.

Here is my *.babelrc*:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", 
      {
        "targets": { "ie": "10" }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is not the dependency also transpiled?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue with a different npm package.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: No worries, I ended up not using that npm package.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your config with: `mix.dump()`;

b/c your rules and test look good (helpful & worked for me in different scenario).

I'd give a try to `mix.babelConfig(<your config>)` - seems to be more explicit to me